# Eclipse and JDK 7

Tags: eclipse, java, java-7

I wish to find out does anyone have problem compiling JDK 7 code with Eclipse? Because currently I only able use JRE 7 in Eclipse to test run but as for trying to use JDK 7 features into my code, it will state it will not support.

Comment: What version of Eclipse?  Personally, I'm sticking with JDK 6 (the last non-Oracle) version for a while...

Comment: Currently I am using the latest version of Eclipse which is Indigo.

Comment: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/ is the new reference impl and its open source

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eclipse 3.8 M1 (Juno) is the earliest stable version to have support for Java 7. Java 7 support will also be available in the upcoming 3.7.1 release.

Unfortunately, since Java 7 released after Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) release, the Java 7 support could not make it to 3.7.